# Create Android Carousel

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I need to create carousel something like as i attach an image. I used Jazzy View Pager and implement its Rotation effects to rotate down effects of view, but it didn't help me out. Here is a link of Jazzy View Pager which i used

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/JazzyViewPager

Even i had tried **mViewPager.setPageMargin(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels / -5);**

I have seen IOS application which already implement View Pager which i need to create, here is URL of viewpager of ios, but i didn't find this for Android

https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Do you have any idea how can i achieve this ? Please guys help me out of this.

[image]

Comment: something like this ? http://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/

Comment: No, not like that coverflow I had worked with that too, but its not like what I actually want.

Comment: oww so you actually want something like the picture you posted ?

Comment: Yeah exactly, i need to create carousel something like as i attached image.

Comment: Well ok and you say that jazzyviewpager isn't working ? Give more details please. Because the animation rotate down should works !!

Comment: JazzyViewPager helped me but not as I need it to do, I need Prev and Next pages of ViewPager partially display on default as a part of screen not on swapping.

Comment: Ohh i see i see, maybe. That will be difficult to find some pre-made library for that. Maybe try to change some parameters in Jazzy view pager ?

Comment: I had tried, as i mentioned above mViewPager.setPageMargin(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels / -5);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37507/discussion-between-shahzeb-khowaja-and-yume117)

Comment: I had tried this

"mViewPager.setPageMargin(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels / -5);" to get partial view of ViewPager but it could not worked for me.

Comment: have you got the solution for your question Shahzed